# ¿Cerrar o detectar docx abierto?

Tags: c#, docx

Hola es una app muy simple que imprime una nota en un docx el problema es que no se como una vez impreso el docx puedo cerrarlo o detectar que este abierto para avisar al usuario y que lo cierre y no ejecutar devuelta la accion hasta que usuario cierre el docx (debido a que da error si lo ejecuta otra vez) El errror es  "System.IO.IOException...
"The process cannot acces the file ..... because it is being used by another process" .Agradeceria cualquier aporte o alternativa que me puedan dar para ello. Desde ya gracias.
El Código(simplificado pero que tapoco funciona) es:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    string filename= System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "/" + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + ".docx";
    DocX documento;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();    
    }

    private void BtnImprimir_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        documento = DocX.Create(filename);
        documento.InsertParagraph("Nota impresa");
        documento.Save();
        Process.Start(filename);
       
    }
```

}

Comment: Que libreria usas para trabajar con el word?

Comment: Agregué el packete Xceed DocX

Comment: Prueba [este metodo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/937558/579895) para detectar si el archivo está en uso. No lo he usado personalmente, asi que no puedo asegurar que te sirva aunque tiene buena pinta.